# Installing PyTorch with Python version 3.11 in a Docker container

Tags: python, docker, pytorch, python-3.11

I see on the official PyTorch page that PyTorch supports Python versions 3.8 to 3.11.

When I actually try to install PyTorch + CUDA in a Python 3.11 Docker image, it seems unable to find CUDA drivers, e.g.

```
FROM python:3.11.4
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=pip-build,target=/root/.cache/pip \
    pip install torch torchaudio
ENV PATH="/usr/local/nvidia/bin:${PATH}" \
    NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all \
    NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all
```

Then, inside the container, I see that `torch.version.cuda` is `None`

Compare this to

```
FROM pytorch/pytorch
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=pip-build,target=/root/.cache/pip \
    pip install torchaudio
ENV PATH="/usr/local/nvidia/bin:${PATH}" \
    NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all \
    NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all
```

Inside the container I see that `torch.version.cuda` is `12.1`

PyTorch claims they're compatible with Python 3.11, has anybody actually been able to use PyTorch+CUDA with Python 3.11?

Tried running Docker images with Python 3.11.4

Tried running the Conda docker image and installing pytorch, but kept getting errors that the images couldn't be found

Comment: This might help https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-install-pytorch-on-the-gpu-with-docker/

Answer (score 0):

Update - think I solved it myself. Kind of dumb, but I just upgrade the Python version in my Dockerfile. I'm sure this results in something breaking, but I haven't run into it yet.

```
FROM pytorch/pytorch

RUN conda update -n base -c defaults conda && \
    conda install -y python=3.11 && \
    conda update --all --yes

CMD ["python", "--version"]
```